# Can someone please identify this USB cable?

Tags: usb, connector

I have looked online and still have not been able to identify the type of connector this is. It came with a cheap Chinese product; the seller is MIA/closed down.

The closest I have seen is a i-USB7 cable but I think that plug is a little larger than the one I have.  I don't THINK it's a CB-USB7 cable but I can't tell for sure.  The second pic shows the unknown plug/connector next to a micro USB connector.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw3xH.jpg]

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Mini-USB+8+pin+Digital+Camera&source=lmns&bih=647&biw=1218&client=firefox-b-1-d&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg37uT4YnrAhXDcqwKHRNRCVAQ_AUoAHoECAEQAA

Comment: what kind of product/device?

Comment: It could be any device that adopted that usb format.

Comment: and what kind of plug is at the other end? USB-A or micro USB B or s.th. else?

Comment: The other end is USB-A

Comment: I have this kind of cable to connect to Panasonic Lumix DMC-ZS8 camera, yes, 8 pins. But you never know for sure with old proprietary connectors.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a [Mini USB 8 pin](https://pinoutguide.com/DigitalCameras/micro_usb_8pin_camera_pinout.shtml) connector (it's a proprietary adapter, haven't seen it around for a while).

Comment: I think you nailed it.  Also.. anything proprietary is certainly not **U**SB.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I think the "USB" applies to the "other side of the cable"...  the "full term" apparently is `8 pin UC-E6`or `8 pin UC-E6 like-mini-usb proprietary connector`...   but those are just educated guesses (hopefully good ones), I haven't really looked at it in depth.

Comment: @FrankThomas this isn't a "real" mini USB connector though (at least not a standard one, as SeñorCMasMas points out correctly) but maybe I understood you wrong?!

Comment: Nope, you are correct. nothing to see here.

Comment: This is my first time using this site and I have to say I am very surprised at the help I have received so far.  Thank you guys!

Comment: @BabaLuchi glad I could help, don't forget to accept the answer if it resolved your question (unless it didn't).

Comment: Was looking exactly for this, thank you for the answer @Albin, highly appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

That's a micro HDMI to mini HDMI cable. The smaller connector being micro HDMI.

Comment: But the larger connector doesn't look at all like mini HDMI (while looking extremely like micro USB). It has like 1/3rd of the pins of a mini HDMI connector.

Comment: sorry, no. One end is USB, the other is definitively NOT HDMI